# Как достать дробные числа из файла?

Tags: java

Есть txt-файл, в нем находятся числа - вперемешку целые и дробные (формата "1,3"). Подскажите как на Java вытянуть оттуда только дробные числа?

Comment: А дробные вида 10/13 или 1.3 или 1,3?

Comment: Регулярным выражением

Comment: Через запятую 1,3

Answer (score 2):

Строку, после получения из файла, проверяете, как Вам уже посоветовали, регулярным выражением:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    System.out.println(checkWithRegExp("123,456"));  
    System.out.println(checkWithRegExp("45,9"));  
    System.out.println(checkWithRegExp("7.6"));  
    System.out.println(checkWithRegExp("0.78"));   
}  

public static boolean checkWithRegExp(String userNameString)
{  
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d*[\\.\\,]\\d+$");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(userNameString);  
    return m.matches();  
}
```

Как то так наверно. Учитывается только точка и запятая. А потом уже парсите строку средствами double Java.

Comment: Ошибки в вашей регулярке: (1) ^* - это множестве начал одной строки? :) Такое бывает? (2) в целой части необязательно должно содержаться значения. Дробь может начинаться с разделителя, то есть с точки. (3) Почему максимум девять знаков может быть в целой и дробной части?

Comment: Про (1) не понял. (2) - поправил - В целой части необязательно должно содержаться значения - это спорно - многие математические системы такого не позволяют. (3) - поправил - Нет Java под рукой, не помню как неограниченное число повторов.

Comment: Да, теперь регулярка верно будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Построчно читаете файл и проверяете каждую строку по регулярному выражению `line.matches("^(\\d)*([\\,\\.]){1}(\\d){1,}$")`.

Поэкспериментировать с регулярными выражениями можно здесь: [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output).

Пример ниже (могут быть ошибки, не компилировал):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line;  
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(line.matches("^(\\d)*([\\,\\.]){1}(\\d){1,}$")) {
    System.out.println("Бинго! Дробное число = " + line);
  }
}
```